# converting AccountBase (and similar types) from the Plaid API into JSON format

Tags: python, json, plaid

The Plaid API returns data in a format that is similar to but not quite JSON. For example a (sandboxed, not real data) query for "accounts" returns

```
{'account_id': 'xllNjaMoAoCPvNVLAN89t1WaL1KXZxsn56pqb',
 'balances': {'available': 100.0,
              'current': 110.0,
              'iso_currency_code': 'USD',
              'limit': None,
              'unofficial_currency_code': None},
 'mask': '0000',
 'name': 'Plaid Checking',
 'official_name': 'Plaid Gold Standard 0% Interest Checking',
 'subtype': 'checking',
 'type': 'depository'}
```

This is typed "AccountBase" (or similarly named alternatives for items and transactions). In their demo code for Python they presume the use of the Flask `jsonify()` command, but I'm not using Flask. From the shell, `jsonpickle.encode()` works, but it doesn't work within PHP for reasons that are beyond me. `json.dumps()` won't attempt to convert AccountBase.

AccountBase objects do print() neatly, but the result is a string which can not be converted into JSON in any useful way.

I ask the community — how might one convert an AccountBase (or ItemBase, or TransactionBase) object into JSON?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more on what happens when `jsonpickle.encode()` is called from PHP / what errors you're getting? It seems like troubleshooting that issue would go a long way toward solving this problem.

Comment: @Alex I agree that would be a nice solution. `jsonpickle.encode()` works fine when run from the shell, but this code needs to be called by PHP as rendered by Apache, and Apache (despite using the exact same `/usr/bin/python3` as the shell) won't `import jsonpickle`. I have spent many hours on this but welcome any ideas you've got. `Venv`, for what's it's worth, makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a noble answer, but I eventually gave up and installed the jsonpickle library with `sudo pip3` instead of `pip3`, and that seems to have solved it.